# Why does not hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter work?

Tags: hooks, blocks, users

I'm implementing a `hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter` for the user login block.

```
function mymodule_block_view_user_login_alter(&$data, $block) {
    drupal_set_message($block->module);
}
```

According to the **block** table, the module is **user** and delta is **login**.
But, the hook was not invoked and the message was not printed out as expected. I'm using D7.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hook is called right before a specific block is rendered. If the block isn't present in the page, the hook is not invoked. Replace that hook with `hook_block_view_alter()`, and it will get invoked for every block shown in the page.

Bear in mind that Drupal caches the hooks implemented from a module; if you alter the code of an enabled module, Drupal will not know the module has a new hook. Disable the module before editing its code, and re-enable it after editing its code; in that way, Drupal will clear its cache, and notice there is a new hook, using it when necessary.

Comment: Just flushing the cashes worked for me. I did not need disable/enable the module. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you disable, and re-enable a module, you are also flushing the cache. `:)`

Comment: Regarding with your first paragraph, `hook_block_view_alter` does not also work without flushing the cache.